# Support pagination of events in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to use FullCalendar for displaying the events in the monthly, daily, weekly and timeline view. Events can be huge in amount (approx, 100000) and also events are nested. So for performance improvement, I want to use pagination for getting events (i.e. /events?page=1&start=0&limit=100) in the GET api. Does this calendar have support for pagination for events?

Comment: fullCalendar supports only loading the events which occur within the dates shown in the currently loaded view (such as only the events for the current month, week or day, for example). See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed for details. (P.S. I'm not sure how your paging idea would work in practice, because there seems to be no relationship between a page and the date range viewable in the calendar. Have you got any idea how you'd reconcile those? The date-based functionality fullCalendar provides seems more sensible, and it still supports only loading a subset of events each time.)

Comment: However, you didn't mention exactly how your 100,000 events are spread out over time. If you find you are still loading 100s of events into a single month or week, for example, then you'll still have a performance issue. At that moment you might want to consider a way of splitting further into subsets (e.g. pagination within a date range), but you'd have to write some extra code and UI to help the calendar handle that. You can add custom parameters to the request to your server (see the link above) so you could e.g. add a page ID or something, and vary it based on user input.